# AngularJS make custom form field.error act like "required"

Tags: angularjs

I am validating my forms both in the client and in my API when sent.
If validation fails in my backend I want to show identical messages as I do when my client validation fails. To do this I use the following piece of code when a field fails in the backend.

```
#Template
<span class="registration-error" ng-show="accPasswordForm.password.$error.required">*</span>
<span class="registration-error" ng-show="accPasswordForm.password.$error.authfail">Authentication failed</span>
<input ng-model="changePasswordForm.password" name="password" type="password" authfail required/>

#Controller ( I set this if the password field throws a validation error in my API )
scope.myForm.password.$setValidity('authfail', false);
```

This works fine, but the problem is that I want this $setValidity to be set to true when I start typing in the password field again. Same behavior as the required error has. Ive tried in different ways to watch the field input but I seem to always fail getting it to work.

Someone able to  give me a hint/code snippet on how I can manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can do this:

```
#Template
<span class="registration-error" ng-show="accPasswordForm.password.$error.required">*</span>
<span class="registration-error" ng-show="server_error_auth || accPasswordForm.password.$error.authfail">Authentication failed</span>
<input ng-model="changePasswordForm.password" ng-change="server_error_auth=false" name="password" type="password" authfail required/>

#Controller ( I set this if the password field throws a validation error in my API )
$scope.server_error_auth = true;
```

Comment: Hmm that only shows the error message when the API validation fails. It does not however set the actual field to invalid. Nor does the error message disapear when I start typing in the field again.

Comment: Well, it's pseudo code. Edited to make it hide when typing. Check that variable also when submitting, as variant.

Comment: Thank you OZ_, that helped me. I changed your example running accPasswordForm.password.$setValidity('authfail', true) in ng-change instead. Worked as I wanted!